# Is there a way to force a function to error globally in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I've run into a situation wherein it might be beneficial to throw an error wherever a particular function is called in a JavaScript program. By which, I don't mean a reference to the function, but any and all references to the function, i.e., the function itself.

```js
let doThing = ()=>console.log("Hello, world!");

// refer to the thing doThing refers to
let a = doThing;

// change what doThing refers to
doThing = ()=>{throw new Error()}; // This won't work for my use case

// "Hello, world!"
a(); // Because a still points to the working function

let b = a;

// kill what a points to
killFunctionSymbol(a); // Instead, I want something like this

// After which, everything fails...
a(); // Error
b(); // Error
```

I've read elsewhere that it's impossible to mutate the body of a function. But, in my case, I'm not sure I need to mutate the body. I just need the call to error. Is there any way I can achieve this? Is there some way I can alter the prototype such that it always breaks?

Comment: You'll need to prepare the original function for this purpose, for instance with a proxy

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It may be an XY problem, and there's a better way to achieve the ultimate goal.

Comment: @Barmar I'm experimenting with an extra layer of security in an application. Basically, I want to make it impossible to call a method without following a certain protocol. (Think traps in low-level programming.) The way I think I can achieve this is by copying the method into routine that respects the protocol, then breaking the original method.

Comment: @trincot See my comment to Barmar. I can't prepare the method to do that. In essence, the piece I'm working on right now is this preparation.

Comment: If you cannot design your function to have this behaviour from the start, then you are without luck. It is not possible in my opinion.

Comment: @trincot Thanks! Figured it might not be due to the malicious counterpart of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @LiamMonninger What kind of "protocol" are you thinking of? What do you want to secure your application against? What secrets does the protocol protect?

Comment: @Bergi I was roughly trying to see what it would take to make a JS ~OS. I was able to get to the point wherein it's impossible (I think) to call ~traps in the the ~OS without wrapping them in a `trap()` method. This trap method runs what I called the protocol above. Functions are copied and wrapped in a special way to enable this. But, I thought it would be a more complete solution to also disable the original function.

In the scheme of what I'm trying to accomplish, I don't need this. I have other means to prevent my system from running functions which aren't appropriately wrapped.

Comment: @LiamMonninger For that, you'll want to have a look at [the *vm* module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) and especially [SES](https://github.com/endojs/endo/tree/master/packages/ses). It allows you to run arbitrary JS code that cannot get access to anything that you don't explicitly grant.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! I was thinking of including vm execution and SES at a bit higher level in my system. But, maybe I have that backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a Proxy. I have to say I'm always on the lookout to use proxies so this is a perfect use case.

Here is a very basic implementation of a proxy that hijacks the call to a function based on some external value

```
const doThing = (arg1, arg2) => `Hello World! ${arg1} ${arg2}`;

let killSwitch = false;

const handler = {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    if (killSwitch) {
      throw new Error('Kill switch engaged');
    }

    return target(...argumentsList);
  }
};

const regular = doThing;
const withProxy = new Proxy(doThing, handler);

console.log(regular('foo1', 'bar1'));
console.log(withProxy('foo2', 'bar2'));

killSwitch = true;
console.log(withProxy('foo3', 'bar3'));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Hope this helps.

Comment: This kind of dependency injection is roughly what's taking place in my protocol (for a lot of different desired effects). But, I was hoping I might be able to kill methods which are originally created outside of my protocol too.

Comment: Why a proxy? A wrapper function would sufficient.

Comment: @LiamMonninger As long as the other party of your protocol has a way to get their hands on the original function (say `regular` in the above snippet) before you get the chance to hide it, then no, it is not possible.